# File not found error for no apparent reason?

Tags: java, android, image, save, storage

My application should save a `piechart` as a png on the `external storage`. However this error appears:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/SAVE IMAGE EXAMPLE/myimage.png (No such file or directory)
```

I followed the instructions to add this kind of functionality very closely (From this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1YjlaPvYxs)), but yet the error appears. The app has the permission to write to external storage, I added the permission in my android_manifest.xml.

Can you guys spot the error? Because i can not.

If you also can't find the error, can you recommend any other way to do this?

Im using MPAndroidChart, but i don't really think it has to do with this, because i could try to save any other object and the error remains.

The **code** is

```
final PieChart piechart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.piechart);  

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick (View v) {
    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Chart Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    piechart.setCenterText("Test");
    Bitmap bitmap;
    OutputStream output;

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.id.piechart);

    File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()+"/SAVE IMAGE EXAMPLE");
    dir.mkdirs();

    File file = new File(dir, "myimage.png");

    try {
       output = new FileOutputStream(file);

       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
       output.flush();
       output.close();


    }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
 } 
});
```

**FULL ERROR**

```
    W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/SAVE IMAGE EXAMPLE/myimage.png (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
W/System.err:     at com.pies.quickpie.Main$1$3.onClick(Main.java:175)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Check if you have the exact case of the path and name correct, Android, being based on Linux, has a case sensitive file system.

Comment: Do you have access rights to the storage. External storage might require a permission.

Comment: i have @dawnkeeper , added the permission in my android_manifest.xml

Comment: `can you elaborate what that axactly means @john16384 ? sorry, i'm new

Comment: Check if `dir.mkdirs();` actually returns `true` -- if it doesn't, the dirs will not have been created.

Comment: what is the android version on which you are testing this? i doubt it's a runtime permission model issue

Comment: `dir.mkdirs();`. Only call mkdirs() if the directory does not exist with dir.exists(). Then check the return value!. This has been said before. If the directory cannot be created and hence not exists then display a toast to the user saying so. And return. Dont continue with your code then as it makes little sense trying to create a file in a directory that does not exist.

Comment: @PavneetSingh I'm running it on a virtual device with android nougat

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [`Runtime Permission model`](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) to get `Storage` Permission from user from marshmallow and above.

[See the example here for storage permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)

Comment: Thank you, I will try this!